# Sum parameters got from Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, count, sum, size

I am creating a script that sums up the sizes of every file under directory red line by line from a file.

Right now the recursive search for files is working and I get a sum for sizes for each line of the source file but I am not sure on how to add all those values together.

What I have right now is:

```
#Read each line of a file for a directory
foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt) {
  #Prints the current line path
  echo $line
  #Prints a count of the files under that path and a sum of all files length
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse $line | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
}
```

The output of this scripts looks like:

```
T:/folder_1/folder_2/2018/12/6/A
Count    : 30
Average  :
Sum      : 522382636
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Length

T:/folder_1/folder_2/2018/12/6/B
Count    : 2
Average  :
Sum      : 2835134
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Length
```

How can I get the sum of every Sum output for every folder, i.e., the sum of all `.Sum` property values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the suggestions by [notjustme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515885/notjustme) and [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers):

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | ForEach-Object -ov results {
  # Calculate the total size for the path at hand, and
  # output the result as a custom object.
  [pscustomobject] @ {
    Path = $_
    Length = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_ | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
  }
} | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum

# Use $results to access the per-path values.
```

Note how an outer `Measure-Object` is used to sum the results of the per-path `Measure-Object` results.

---

If you don't need to store the per-path results and **just want the overall sum**, the solution becomes much simpler, as Ansgar observes:

```
(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Get-Content .\file.txt) -Recurse |
   Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
```

Note how the array of lines output by `Get-Content` is directly passed to `-LiteralPath`, which is supported, because both `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` are defined as `[string[]]` (string *arrays*).